# How to Page Break HTML Content in HTML Renderer

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, html-renderer

I have a project where HTML code is converted to a PDF using HTML Renderer. The HTML code contains a single table. The PDF is displayed but the issue is that the contents of the table are cut off at the end. So is there any solution to the problem?[image]

PdfDocument pdf=new PdfDocument();

```
            var config = new PdfGenerateConfig()
            {
                MarginBottom = 20,
                MarginLeft = 20,
                MarginRight = 20,
                MarginTop = 20,
            };
            //config.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            config.ManualPageSize = new PdfSharp.Drawing.XSize(1080, 828);

            pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config);

            byte[] fileContents = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdf.Save(stream, true);
                fileContents = stream.ToArray();
                return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(fileContents.ToArray()), "application/pdf");
            }
```

Comment: PDFsharp cannot convert HTML. Which tools are you using? Maybe show some code.

Comment: Sorry.. The code is shown..

Answer (score 3):

HTMLRenderer should be able break the table to the next page.
See also:
https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/pull/41

Make sure you are using the latest version. You may have to add those CSS properties.

Also see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37833107/162529

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know page breaks are not supported, but I've done a bit of a work-around (which may not work for all cases) by splitting the HTML into separate pages using a page break class, then adding each page to the pdf.

See example code below:

```
    //This will only work on page break elements that are direct children of the body element.
    //Each page's content must be inside the pagebreak element
    private static PdfDocument SplitHtmlIntoPagedPdf(string html, string pageBreakBeforeClass, PdfGenerateConfig config, PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var htmlBodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

        var tempHtml = string.Empty;
        foreach (var bodyNode in htmlBodyNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (bodyNode.Attributes["class"]?.Value == pageBreakBeforeClass)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempHtml))
                {
                    //add any content found before the page break
                    AddPageToPdf(htmlDoc,tempHtml,config,ref pdf);
                    tempHtml = string.Empty;
                }
                AddPageToPdf(htmlDoc,bodyNode.OuterHtml,config,ref pdf);
            }
            else
            {
                tempHtml += bodyNode.OuterHtml;
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempHtml))
        {
            //add any content found after the last page break
            AddPageToPdf(htmlDoc, tempHtml, config, ref pdf);
        }

        return pdf;
    }

    private static void AddPageToPdf(HtmlDocument htmlDoc, string html, PdfGenerateConfig config, ref PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        var tempDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        tempDoc.LoadHtml(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
        var docNode = tempDoc.DocumentNode;
        docNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerHtml = html;
        var nodeDoc = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(docNode.OuterHtml, config);
        using (var tempMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            nodeDoc.Save(tempMemoryStream, false);
            var openedDoc = PdfReader.Open(tempMemoryStream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            foreach (PdfPage page in openedDoc.Pages)
            {
                pdf.AddPage(page);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call the code as follows:

```
            var pdf = new PdfDocument();
            var config = new PdfGenerateConfig()
            {
                MarginLeft = 5,
                MarginRight = 5,
                PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait,
                PageSize = PageSize.A4
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pageBreakBeforeClass))
            {
                pdf = SplitHtmlIntoPagedPdf(html, pageBreakBeforeClass, config, pdf);
            }
            else
            {
                pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, config);
            }
```

For any html that you want to have in its own page, just put the html inside a div with a class of "pagebreak" (or whatever you want to call it).  If you want to, you could add that class to your css and give it "page-break-before: always;", so that the html will be print-friendly.

Comment: Another implementation of this can be found [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/issues/49). It's a bit easier and you don't need to add extra references

Answer (score 2):

I've just figured out how to make it work, rather than page-break-inside on a TD, do that on the TABLE. Here's the code:

```
table { page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

I'm currently on the following versions (not working on stable versions at the moment):
HtmlRenderer on v1.5.1-beta1
PDFsharp on v1.51.5185-beta